# git Save and Auto Use Merge Strategy Configuration for Specific Files

Tags: git

I use git to manage my remote 'dev' environment for common hosted solutions such as WordPress. It's great, because I can have a sandbox, different custom themes, and all kinds of goodies managed fairly dynamically with some crafty DNS and Apache settings.

I do a `git fetch/pull` every so often, and I have two files that are always ahead of the remote branch, and cause merge conflicts.  `.gitignore` and `.gitmodules`.  Reasons being obvious, I'm extending the software with my own customizations that will never be remitted to the remote source repository.

Is there a way I can store `ours` merge conflict resolution on only specific files?  I'm guessing it would have to do with custom settings in `git config --local`  but having trouble getting what I want.  I'm approaching this by creating a custom merge driver of my own, and then attempting to use the local config file to auto-apply that driver to affected paths given (either in `$local/config` or `.gitattributes`

```
# Custom Merge Strategy Handling for specific files
[core]
    resolveConflict = merge
    path = .gitignore
    path = .gitsubmodules
#define my custom merge driver
[merge "ours"]
    path = .gitignore
    path = .gitsubmodules
```